# Horizontally Scrolling Layouts with Flexbox + Columns

Tags: html, css, multiple-columns, flexbox

Anyone want to help me debug a little experiment I'm working on. I want to use flexbox/multicolumn layout to get a layout similar to what you see in many Windows 8 news app, where the article(s) are in fixed width columns, with a dynamic number of columns depending on the length of the article, that scroll off to the right.

So I whipped up this [CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/tcGuF) but flexbox and the columns don't seem to be working together well. In Firefox, it only shows one column of each, and I can't even tell what's going on in webkit.

What am I screwing up?

(I looked and in Windows 8 html5 apps they seem to use grid layout, but I can't do that since it's IE only)

Comment: I've found a really good example about columns: check it, it could be for your help: http://kaikkonendesign.fi/columns/

Comment: It looks to me like the width of the flex item can't be calculated properly once the columns come into play.  If you look at it in Opera, you can see what's happening a little more clearly.  There's multiple red outlines that appear, and the 2nd columned element begins on top of the 2nd red box:  http://codepen.io/cimmanon/pen/LcJft