# Stretch Container to Fit CSS Columns

Tags: html, css

I'm having an issue with the CSS `columns` property. Namely, I cannot seem to get the container surrounding them to stretch to the width of the columns as seen here: http://jsfiddle.net/niaconis/43k5s/5/

Seems a lot like the similar issue with floats, only horizontal instead of vertical, but the pseudo-element clearfix doesn't help with this one.

How can I get the container to completely wrap the columns?

P.S. I know about the [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), but this is merely a curiosity. I don't care about achieving the layout from the example. I do care about finding out why the container doesn't stretch to wrap its contents.

Comment: Can you please post **your** code demonstrating the problem directly into this question?

Comment: Some browsers have a difficult time calculating the proper width of the element in certain instances when you use columns (see this question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16600007/horizontally-scrolling-layouts-with-flexbox-columns).  The absolute positioning is what's breaking it in this particular instance.

Comment: @cimmanon That's it! Thanks so much. If you write this up as an answer, I'll be happy to accept it =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The absolute positioning of your element is causing the browser to incorrectly calculate how wide it should be when using the `columns` property.  Remove it and the element stretches as it should.